# Is there a way to "intercept" react state update, and sanitize/trim/... the value before it is set

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Assuming there is a state in a functional component that holds a string; since this state is updated from multiple places in the component, is it possible to "intercept" all updates, and always perform some operation such as trimming the value before it is set? Would it be better to utilize useReducer here?

Answer (score 0):

you would create a reusable function for that and apply it where it's needed:

```
  const [name, setName] = useState('');

  const updateName = (value) => {
    // do some validation (like avoid numbers)
    if(value.match(/[0-9]+/)) return
    // some normalize
    setName(value.trim());
  }

  return (
    <>
      <label for="name">Name</label>
      <input id="name" value={name} onChange={e => updateName(e.target.value)} />
      <button onClick={() => updateName('C3P0')}>Try droid name</button>
    </>
  )
```

or use some specific library that has built-in validations like [yup](https://github.com/jquense/yup)